# Partially hidden button jumps up when focused in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a form with a submit button positioned absolutely, moved to the bottom-right corner and partially hidden (it looks like quarter-circle on the design). When I place focus on one of the input field and then press TAB to move focus to the button, it jumps up and shifts the entire form content up.

Styles are pretty basic:

```
<form action="">
   <input type="text" width="100px" placeholder="Text input">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

CSS

```
form {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #cef;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  right: -50px;
  bottom: -50px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

Here's fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/4zhL68z0/1/
Chrome version is 54.0.2840.87 (64-bit)

Clipping didn't work, changing placement from bottom: -20px to top: 500px didn't work, so any ideas are welcome.

Comment: I am not sure what is the desired outcome. The shift of the form is expected behaviour on every browser. Browsers will scroll to the focused content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the button in a container and positioning that absolute. Here's a quick fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/giwan/4zhL68z0/2/

```

```
.button-container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  right: -50px;
  bottom: -50px;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 360px;
  border: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```

Alternatively you could use an image to get the desired effect on the button.

Comment: Hey Giwan, it kind of worked, but it still jumps up if the container has padding or button has some offset from the container. I'll wait a bit and if nothing better comes up, I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: This example is working fine for me in Firefox, but unfortunately not in Chrome.

Comment: @DarekKay I'm not sure if this is a bug in Chrome but if you add padding-top:0px to the button container it seems to work again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's work for me.

```
    button {
       position: absolute;
       display: block;
       height: 100px;
       width: 100px;
       right: 0px;
       bottom: 0px;
       background: yellow;
       -moz-border-radius: 100px 0 0 0;
       -webkit-border-radius: 100px 0 0 0;
      }
```